# Finding sum of every combination of two numbers in an array in Ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays

I'm trying to create a function that checks if two numbers within an array have a sum of zero.

```
[1,2,3,4,5] => false
[1,2,3,-2,5] => true
```

This is what I have so far but I can't figure it out:

```
def zero_sum?(arr)

  arr.each do |num|
    arr.each do |num2|
      if (num.to_i + num2.to_i) == 0
        true
      else
        false
      end
    end
  end

end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to know whether any combination of 2 elements adds up to zero. You can pretty much write that down verbatim:

```
arr.combination(2).any? {|a, b| (a + b).zero? }
```

Comment: Gives different result for a list including a single zero. However, true to the English wording. I am torn.

Comment: @Amadan `combination` doesn't mix two array elements of the same index, which is why a single `0` yields false.

Comment: @mbratch: Yes, I know why. I'm just saying the OP has different expectations in his English and in his code. I followed code, Jörg followed words, and consequently we have different results. Only OP can say who is right. :)

Comment: The OP's code has wrong logic anyway (in handling `true` and `false` symmetrically), so it cannot be relied on. I also took the wording.

Comment: This is exactly what I want it to do, but is there any way to do it without using .combination ?? Sorry for being difficult, I'm just trying to understand basic Ruby...

Comment: @punkinbread: If you want to use your original code, you have to do two things then: a) insert `return` before `true` to break the loop, and b) insert `next if num == num2` before the `if`.

Comment: @Amadan That logic is actually wrong. A single match would determine the return value `true`, but a single non-match does not determine `false`.

Comment: Understanding the methods provided by `Enumerable` *is* basic Ruby. In fact, it solves pretty much 80% of all basic programming problems.

Comment: @Jörg `combination` is provided by Array, not Enumerable.

Answer (score 2):

You need `return true` instead of `true`.

This way, the value in the block is `true` when it needs to be, but the looping continues, and finally `each` returns `arr`.

Also, can be written shorter, but it is not as efficient:

```
def zero_sum?(arr)
  arr.product(arr).any? { |x, y| x + y == 0 }
end
```

A bit less nice but efficient:

```
def zero_sum?(arr)
  arr.product(arr) { |x, y| return true if x + y == 0 }
  false
end
```

Comment: To expand on the “efficiency” comments: both solutions are O(n²), however the practical time complexity of the second is, on average, half that of the first, and the memory complexity of the second is as little as 1/nth of the first.

Answer (score 1):

an easy way to do it is:

```
def zero_sum?(arr)
  arr.count(0) > 1 or
  arr.-([0]).any?{|e| arr.include?(-e)}
end
```

Comment: I couldn't figure out what `arr.-([])` was until I removed the dot and found it made no difference.  As the parens are just to avoid `].`, it's the same as `(arr-[0])`.  You could also use `arr.uniq`, but that would be less descriptive.

Answer (score 1):

another way to do this:-

```
array.product(array).any?{|arr| arr.sum.zero?}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
arr.count(0) > 1 or 
  arr.uniq.map(&:abs).group_by(&:to_i).values.map(&:size).max > 0
```

I really don't think this is the best answer, but it might be of interest to someone. (Borrowed part before `or` from @sawa.)

Answer (score 0):

```
arr.each_cons(2).select{|array|array.inject(:+) == 0}.count > 0
```